# Помогите разобраться (javascript)

Tags: javascript

всем привет
помогите разобраться в коде, который приведен ниже.

```js
var employers = ['Alex', '', 'ludmila', 'Viktor', '', 'oleg', 'iNna', 'Ivan', 'Alex', 'Olga', ' Ann'];

var employersNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < employers.length; i++) {
 if (employers[i].length > 0 && employers[i].length != '') {
  employersNames.push(employers[i]);
 }
}
for (var i = 0; i < employersNames.length; i++) {
 employersNames[i] = employersNames[i].toLowerCase().trim();
}

var sponsors = {
    cash: [40000, 5000, 30400, 12000],
    eu: ['SRL', 'PLO', 'J&K'],
    rus: ['RusAuto', 'SBO']
};

function calcCash(own) {
    own = own || 0;
    var everyCash = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var total = own;
    for (var i = 0; i < everyCash[1].length; i++) {
        total += +everyCash[1][i];
    }
    return total;
}

var money = calcCash(null, sponsors.cash);

function makeBusiness(owner, director, cash, emp) {
    director = director || 'Victor';
    var sumSponsors = sponsors.eu.concat(sponsors.rus, 'unexpected sponsor');
    console.log('We have a business. Owner: ' + owner + ', director: ' + director + '. Our budget: ' + cash + '. And our employers: ' +
    emp);
    console.log('And we have a sponsors: ');
    console.log.apply(null, sumSponsors);
    console.log('Note. Be careful with ' + sponsors.eu[0] + ". It's a huge risk.");
}
makeBusiness.apply(null, ['Sam', null, money, employersNames]);
```

интересуют следующие строки кода:

```
var everyCash = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 
       for (var i = 0; i < everyCash[1].length; i++) {
           total += +everyCash[1][i];
```

не понимаю от слова совсем.
можете подробнее объяснить создание двумерного массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arguments - все аргументы переданные в функцию, в данном случае мы передаем два аргумента `var money = calcCash(null, sponsors.cash);`  null и массив с деньгами.

null в функции calcCash преобразуется в ноль `own = own || 0;`

далее мы преобразуем arguments в js массив (arguments сам по себе массивом не является) таким способом

```
var everyCash = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

теперь в everyCash  хранится массив аргументов функции  [0, sponsors.cash]

а далее мы просто суммируем 0 и все значения sponsors.cash

```
var total = own;
for (var i = 0; i < everyCash[1].length; i++) {
    total += +everyCash[1][i];
}
return total;
```

и получаем сумму спонсорских вкладов (точно не знаю, что значат эти числа).

первый аргумент функции calcCash - это, видимо, начальная сумма, которая у нас уже есть, она может быть нулевой как в примере